# python PointCloud2 read_points() problem

Tags: python, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on a kinect project. I'm trying to write a pair of files that test out the PointCloud2 sensor message. I don't know how to make the 'listener' python script read the value that I have created in the 'talktest' script. I am using the class defined here:

sensor_msgs/point_cloud2.py (I could not post a link)

This is my code. These are my includes. I use them pretty much the same in both files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 as pc2
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2, PointField
```

This is the 'talktest' code.

```
#talktest
def test():
    rospy.init_node('talktest', anonymous=True)
    pub_cloud = rospy.Publisher("camera/depth_registered/points", PointCloud2)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        pcloud = PointCloud2()
        # make point cloud
        cloud = [[33,22,11],[55,33,22],[33,22,11]]
        pcloud = pc2.create_cloud_xyz32(pcloud.header, cloud)
        pub_cloud.publish(pcloud)
        rospy.loginfo(pcloud)
        rospy.sleep(1.0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        test()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Then I have written a script that listens for point cloud data. It always throws a AttributeError.

```
#listener
def listen():
    rospy.init_node('listen', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("camera/depth_registered/points", PointCloud2, callback_kinect)

def callback_kinect(data) :
    # pick a height
    height =  int (data.height / 2)
    # pick x coords near front and center
    middle_x = int (data.width / 2)
    # examine point
    middle = read_depth (middle_x, height, data)
    # do stuff with middle
    

def read_depth(width, height, data) :
    # read function
    if (height >= data.height) or (width >= data.width) :
        return -1
    data_out = pc2.read_points(data, field_names=None, skip_nans=False, uvs=[width, height])
    int_data = next(data_out)
    rospy.loginfo("int_data " + str(int_data))
    return int_data

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        listen()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

I always get this error:

> [ERROR] [WallTime: 1389040976.560028]
> bad callback: <function
> callback_kinect at 0x2a51b18>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py",
> line 681, in _invoke_callback
> cb(msg)   File "./turtlebot_listen.py", line 98, in
> callback_kinect
> left = read_depth (left_x, height, data)   File "./turtlebot_listen.py",
> line 126, in read_depth
> int_data = next(data_out)   File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sensor_msgs/point_cloud2.py",
> line 74, in read_points
> assert isinstance(cloud, roslib.message.Message) and
> cloud._type ==
> 'sensor_msgs/PointCloud2', 'cloud is
> not a sensor_msgs.msg.PointCloud2'
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no
> attribute 'message'

Can anyone tell me how to use this library correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115136/python-pointcloud2-read_points()-problem/) by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2014-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try adding the following import statement after the 'import rospy' line:

```
 from roslib import message
```

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2014-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on 2014-01-07**:
this worked. Thanks. Also, I had to change the read_points() line like this:
   `data_out = pc2.read_points(data, field_names=None, skip_nans=False, uvs=[[width, height]])` 
note the double square braces around width and height!! Thanks again.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2014-01-07**:
Excellent!  I haven't used the uvs argument (yet) so that is good to know for the future.

**Comment by [sabruri1](https://answers.ros.org/users/31357/sabruri1/) on 2017-07-26**:
Hello! Thank's for your help. I have a question. When I try to test your code, into read_depth method, variable "int_data" has three field. What are they?

**Comment by [Badal](https://answers.ros.org/users/82298/badal/) on 2021-09-29**:
They are Pointcloud XYZ data for the center (u,v ) pixel correspondence.